# Formatting any values less than one to be 0?

Tags: python, formatting

Is there a way I can use Python formatting to round and values between .5 and 1 to 0? Instead of rounding it up to 1.

For Example:

```
> number = 0.75
> print("Number {0:.0f}".format(number))
1
```

Instead of rounding it up to 1 I would like it to be 0 instead. Is this possible with formatting?

Answer (score 2):

`int` floors floats:

```
In [13]: number = 0.75

In [14]: 'Number {0:d}'.format(int(number))
Out[14]: 'Number 0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not truncate?

```
>>> int(0.6)
0
>>> print("Number {0:.0f}".format(int(number)))
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Truncating with `int` has already been mentioned. The problem is that for negative numbers, `int` truncates towards 0, rather than negative infinity. So in general it may better to use `math.floor` instead, which may also make the intention clearer. Note that `math.floor` will return a float.

```
> import math
> number = .75
> print "Number {:.0f}".format(math.floor(number))
0
```